# unable to reproduce android Room database migration crash reported in firebase crashlytics

Tags: android, crash, android-room, database-migration, crashlytics

[Crashlytics Crashlytics dashboard here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZCgi.png)
[Crashlytics dashboard Data here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xec9O.png)
Crashlytics is not providing entire Expected: TableInfo and Found: TableInfo

```
# Crashlytics - Stack trace
# Application: com.sboxnw.freeplay
# Platform: android
# Version: 4.1.2 (1000115)
# Issue: 981a792c3e89fdd2221f0e08adedd4a0
# Session: 63A9433E002A00010FB87EC35F269544_DNE_0_v2
# Date: Mon Dec 26 2022 12:16:23 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle: downloads_table(com.sboxnw.freeplay.models.cms.mylist.DownloadsModel).
 Expected:
TableInfo{name='downloads_table', columns={isDrmContent=Column{name='isDrmContent', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, data=Column{name='data', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, partnerContentId=Column{name='partnerContentId', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, lastWatchedTime=Column{name='lastWatchedTime', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, lastSyncDuration=Column{name='lastSyncDuration', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, contentId=Column{name='contentId', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, duration=Column{name='duration', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, createdAt=Column{name='createdAt', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, lastUpdated=Column{name='lastUpdated', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, downloadPath=Column{name='downloadPath', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, contentSize=Column{name='contentSize', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, lastPlayerPosition=Column{name='lastPlayerPosition', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, state=Column{name='state', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, downloadPercentage=Column{name='downloadPercentage', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue<truncated: 5313 chars>
       at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade(RoomOpenHelper.java:103)
       at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onUpgrade(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:183)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:416)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:316)
       at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:151)
       at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:112)
       at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:706)
       at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:483)
       at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:526)
       at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(DBUtil.java:86)
       at com.sboxnw.freeplay.data.database.ContinueWatchingDao_Impl$10.call(ContinueWatchingDao_Impl.java:688)
       at com.sboxnw.freeplay.data.database.ContinueWatchingDao_Impl$10.call(ContinueWatchingDao_Impl.java:685)
       at androidx.room.CoroutinesRoom$Companion$createFlow$1$1$1.invokeSuspend(CoroutinesRoom.kt:128)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

AsyncTask #3:
       at libcore.io.Linux.poll(Linux.java)
       at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.poll(ForwardingOs.java:168)
       at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.poll(BlockGuardOs.java:263)
       at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.poll(ForwardingOs.java:168)
       at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:266)
       at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:192)
       at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:134)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:631)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:182)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:145)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:302)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:245)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:262)
       at com.sboxnw.sdk.GetConfigTask.doInBackground(ConnectToNetworkTask.java:702)
       at com.sboxnw.sdk.GetConfigTask.doInBackground(ConnectToNetworkTask.java:661)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

AsyncTask #4:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:230)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:461)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:937)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1091)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

pool-4-thread-1:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:230)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2109)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1091)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

firebase-installations-executor-1:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:230)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2109)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1091)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

DefaultDispatcher-worker-1:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:353)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.park(CoroutineScheduler.kt:795)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.tryPark(CoroutineScheduler.kt:740)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:711)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)

WifiManagerThread:
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

pool-9-thread-1:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:230)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:461)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:937)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1091)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

Timer-5:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:442)
       at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(TimerThread.java:559)
       at java.util.TimerThread.run(TimerThread.java:512)

AsyncTask #1:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:230)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:461)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:937)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1091)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

Firebase-Messaging-Topics-Io:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2067)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1120)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:849)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.0.0:2)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

WM.task-2:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2067)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

ReferenceQueueDaemon:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:442)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:568)
       at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:218)
       at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:140)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

pool-8-thread-1:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:230)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:461)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:937)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1091)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

WM.task-1:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2067)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

AsyncTask #2:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:230)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:461)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:937)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1091)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

WM.task-4:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2067)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

Timer-2:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:442)
       at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(TimerThread.java:559)
       at java.util.TimerThread.run(TimerThread.java:512)

glide-active-resources:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:442)
       at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:190)
       at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:211)
       at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.ActiveResources.cleanReferenceQueue(ActiveResources.java:128)
       at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.ActiveResources$2.run(ActiveResources.java:61)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.ActiveResources$1$1.run(ActiveResources.java:43)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

heartbeat-information-executor:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:230)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2109)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1091)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

FrameMetricsAggregator:
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

GmsDynamite:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:442)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:568)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.0.0:2)

Timer-3:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:442)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:568)
       at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(TimerThread.java:533)
       at java.util.TimerThread.run(TimerThread.java:512)

com.google.firebase.crashlytics.startup1:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2067)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:64)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

pool-27-thread-1:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2067)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

pool-29-thread-1:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:230)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:461)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:937)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1091)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

FinalizerWatchdogDaemon:
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:442)
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:568)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepUntilNeeded(Daemons.java:342)
       at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:322)
       at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:140)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

arch_disk_io_1:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2067)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

ConnectivityThread:
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

arch_disk_io_3:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2067)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

pool-28-thread-1:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:230)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:461)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:937)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1091)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

pool-6-thread-1:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:230)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:461)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:937)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1091)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

pool-3-thread-1:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2067)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

ScionFrontendApi:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:230)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2109)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1091)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

GoogleApiHandler:
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

pool-30-thread-1:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:230)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:461)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
       at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:937)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1091)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Not able to reproduce, We tested this on production apk  and staging debug apk version 4.0.9-4.1.2,4.0.9-4.1.3,  4.1.1 to 4.1.2,4.0.8-4.1.2,4.1.0 to 4.1.2,

4.1.1 to 4.1.2  with downloaded and continue watching content.

As the Expected tableInfo is partially provided in Crashlytics dashboard we are not able to compare the found and expected table in-order to find the root cause for migration failure. Hence in ApplicationModule Added:

fallbackToDestructiveMigration() on databaseBuilder

Gracefully handle missing migration paths

If Room cannot find a migration path for upgrading an existing database on a device to the current version, an IllegalStateException occurs. If it is acceptable to lose existing data when a migration path is missing, call the fallbackToDestructiveMigration() builder method when you create the database:

```
Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, MyDb::class.java, "database-name")
    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
    .build()
```

It is temporary fix we did as we cannot reproduce the crash.

currently we are using custom migration,Upcoming will use auto migration as we are only adding new column or renaming table

Reason for adopting this solution is also because this crash are  Early crashes and Repetitive crashes for users.

Answer (score 0):

> As the Expected tableInfo is partially provided in Crashlytics dashboard we are not able to compare the found and expected table in-order to find the root cause for migration failure.

They way to avoid the Expected .... Found .... issue is to let Room determine the schema for the Found.

That is

1. make the changes to the `@Entity` annotated class(es),
2. compile the project,
3. inspect the Java(generated) (viewable via the Android View).
4. locate the class that is the same name as the `@Database` annotated class but suffixed with **`_Impl`**.
5. in that class there will be a method called **`createAllTables`**,
6. in that method is the SQL for the **Expected** components (tables and indexes). This SQL can be used as the basis for the migration.

   - Note you should ignore the SQL for the creation and insertion into the room_master_table as Room will do the necessary to maintain the table (i.e. store the hash of the schema).

As an example. After compiling the project then:-

[image]

With the **Expected** SQL available, you should be able to ascertain where the discrepancy is or where the discrepancies are.